# Change and keep background color on click

Tags: jquery, colors, background

I am having the following structure on a website I am building:

```
<tr>

        <td class="header link"><a href="x" >X</a></td>
        <td class="header link"><a href="y" >Y</a></td>
        <td class="header link"><a href="z" >Z</a></td>
        <td class="header link"><a href="w" >W</td>

</tr>
```

All cells have the same background color initially.

What I would like to accomplish is the following:

When any of the links is clicked, the background color of the cell containing the link changes to new color and stays changed, until another link is selected.

When the other link is selected, the color of the firstly selected link changes back to the original color, while the cell of the newly selected link changes to new color.

Currently what I have in place is working hover function:

```
$(document).ready(function()
 {    $(function(){ $('.header').hover(function() {$(this).css('background-color', '#EBA521');},         
 function() { $(this).css('background-color', '#6F0000'); });  
 });
 });
```

How do I accomplish the above?

Comment: i don't know if this was accidental when putting it on SO, but your `$(document).ready()` and `$(function(){` do the same thing, and nesting them inside each other might be causing a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('.header.link a').click(function() {
                $('.header.link a').css('background-color', '#6F0000');
                $(this).css('background-color', '#EBA521');
                $(this).data("bgColor", "#EBA521")
                return false;
        });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
        $(function() {
                $('.header.link a').hover(function() {
                        $(this).data("bgColor", $(this).css('background-color'));
                        $(this).css('background-color', '#EBA521');
                }, function() {
                        $(this).css('background-color', $(this).data("bgColor"));
                });
        });
});
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Hbgz3/2/

Comment: And also for making me realize that `css` also has a `(property, value)` syntax. I've always been using maps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! This solution seems to be interfering with the Hover function I have in place - the hover stops working. Would it be possible to keep the two effects - both hover and change-and-keep on click effect without them overriding each other?

Comment: @Veni: Updated the answer. Pls chk

Comment: Thank you! Using the above code now makes the hover function work only until a click event takes place. After that, only the change color-on-click works, without the hover.

Comment: This is exactly the effect I wanted to have in place! Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Use the click handler instead of hover()

```
$(function() {
    $("a").click( function() {
        $(".header.link").css('background-color', '#6F0000');
        $(this).parent().css('background-color', '#EBA521');
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answers! This solution seems to be interfering with the Hover function I have in place - the hover stops working.  Would it be possible to keep the two effects - both hover and change-and-keep on click effect?

Comment: yes, both event handlers should be able to co-exist simultaneously.

Comment: the real problem is that the hover's mouseout function still remains, which means that the color will be reverted back to the #6F0000 value when the mouse leaves.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the .click event in a similar way you used the .hover function:

```
$('.header').click(function(){
  //change color of this
  //change color of all other .header elements to default color
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the color to the link using a data-value.

`data-value="#ffcc00"`

```
$('.header a').click(function() {
    $('.header').css('background-color','#ffffff');
    $(this).parent().css('background-color',$(this).attr('data-value'));
});
```